# How to center the popupview that contain dynamic height content ??

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, swift3, uikit

I am now implementation the pop up dialog for my iOS app according to this youtube video "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=FgCIRMz_3dE".But the problem is I can't set my pop up view to fixed height because there is dynamic height label in my popup view which is inside my popup view controller.Can anyone tell me how to solve this solution?Thanks for your attention.

[image: This is my popup view controller structure.The opacity of underlying background is reduced to see the content of the parent view.]

Here is my code to open popup view controller from parent view controller.

```
let PopUpVC = UIStoryboard(name:"Main", bundle:nil).instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "FeedPopUpViewController") as! FeedPopUpViewController

        self.addChildViewController(PopUpVC)
        PopUpVC.view.frame = self.view.frame
        self.view.addSubview(PopUpVC.view)
        PopUpVC.didMove(toParentViewController: self)
```

Here is my code for FeedPopUpView Controller

```
import UIKit

class FeedPopUpViewController: UIViewController {
    @IBOutlet weak var action_Label: UILabel!

    @IBAction func dismiss(_ sender: Any) {
        print("pop up is dismissed")
        self.view.removeFromSuperview()
    }
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        self.showAnimate()
        super.viewDidLoad()
        print("pop up is created")
    }

    override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        print("pop up is appeared")
    }

    func showAnimate(){

    }
}
```

Comment: Have you setup `FeedPopUpViewController` from storyboard?

Comment: Yes,I have.I can't only make constraint to put my popup in center.Thanks for your attention.

Comment: So, your problem is you don't know how add constraints (in storyboard) to let the white view to be always in the center of the screen, right?

Comment: Yes, I usually give center x to parent view, center y  to parent view, fixed width and fixed height to place a view in center.But I have the dynamic height label inside my popup view.So that I can't make my view to fixed height.Thanks for your attention

Answer (score 0):

```
PopUpVC.view.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.centerXAnchor).isActive = true
```

This should do the work :)

Comment: Thanks for your attention.Can you please give me detail implementations of your anwser?I'm now using storyboard for autolayout.Adding one constraints doesn't work.

Comment: You are adding the PopUpVC view to your current VC: `self.view.addSubview(PopUpVC.view)` Then the `PopUpVC.view` dont now its width and height. I assume that the semi transparent black background is the PopupVC's view background?

You should add height and width to the PopupVC's view too